# How to select multiple checkbox in Accordion using react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How to select multiple checkboxes from accordion?

I am able to select multiple checkboxes whatever I have tried so far. The only problem is when I select checkboxes from one list(**List1**) then select from another list(Any List) and again select from **List1**.

#### Steps to reproduce the issue

[image]

Can somebody help to improve the code or provide any solution/suggestion on how to do this?
**App.js**

```
import AccordionHeader from "./AccordionHeader";
import listData from "./data";
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    lists: listData,
    show: false,
    selectedList: {}
  };
  handleTile = (list) => {
    let getID = !this.state.lists[list.id].active;
    let update = this.state.lists.map((item) =>
      item.id === list.id ? { ...item, active: getID } : item
    );
    this.setState({ lists: update, selectedList: { ...list } });
  };
  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { lists, selectedList } = this.state;
    let obj = lists?.find((filt) => filt.id === selectedList.id);
    obj.innerList.forEach((inner) => {
      if (inner.title === e.target.name) inner.completed = e.target.checked;
    });
    let toggledBoxes = lists.map((list) =>
      list.id === obj.id ? { ...obj } : list
    );
    this.setState({ lists: toggledBoxes });
  };
  render() {
    const { lists } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        {lists.map((ar, index) => (
          <div className="heading" key={index}>
            <AccordionHeader
              active={ar.active}
              index={index}
              onClick={() => this.handleTile(ar)}
            />

            {ar.active ? (
              <React.Fragment>
                {ar.innerList.map((inner) => (
                  <div key={inner.id}>
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      checked={inner.completed}
                      name={inner.title}
                      id={inner.title}
                    />
                    <label>{inner.title}</label>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </React.Fragment>
            ) : null}
          </div>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**AccordionHeader.js**

```
export default function AccordionHeader({ active, index, onClick }) {
  return (
    <div className={active ? "tile is-active" : "tile"} onClick={onClick}>
      <div className="left">
        <div>
          <strong>{`${index}`} </strong>
          <span>Menu</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="right">
        {!active ? 'A' : 'V'}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**data.json**

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "active": false,
    "innerList": [
      { "id": 0, "completed": false, "title": "List 1" },
      { "id": 1, "completed": false, "title": "List 2" },
      { "id": 2, "completed": false, "title": "List 3" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "active": false,
    "innerList": [
      { "id": 0, "completed": false, "title": "Item 1" },
      { "id": 1, "completed": false, "title": "Item 2" },
      { "id": 2, "completed": false, "title": "Item 3" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "active": false,
    "innerList": [
      { "id": 0, "completed": false, "title": "Inner 1" },
      { "id": 1, "completed": false, "title": "Inner 2" },
      { "id": 2, "completed": false, "title": "Inner 3" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "active": false,
    "innerList": [
      { "id": 0, "completed": false, "title": "Sub 1" },
      { "id": 1, "completed": false, "title": "Sub 2" },
      { "id": 2, "completed": false, "title": "Sub 3" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Working Code in codeSandbox - [Multi checkbox in accordion](https://codesandbox.io/s/multi-checkbox-in-accordion-5lol9?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please include a relevant [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here in your question. It's nice that you included a link out to a codesandbox, but external resources tend to decay over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

You are storing a `selectedList` in state, the selected list is the last accordion section toggled open/close. So when you then toggle another section open, *that* one has "focus" and you can't interact with the nested inputs of other accordion sections until you toggle it open/close.

## Solutions

At a minimum these are the suggestions I have to fix/address the above issues.

1. Remove `selectedList` from state. It's not needed and you can derive from UI interaction the section you need to update.

   ```
   state = {
     lists: listData,
     show: false
   };
   ```
2. `handleTile` should simply toggle your accordion sections open/close. Use a functional state update to update from the previous state and shallow copy the array ***and*** item you are toggling the `active` property of.

   ```
   handleTile = (list) => {
     this.setState((prevState) => ({
       lists: prevState.lists.map((item) =>
         item.id === list.id ? { ...item, active: !item.active } : item
       )
     }));
   };
   ```
3. Update `handleChange` to consume a `selectedList` list item. Note this is a curried function that consumes a `selectedList` argument and returns an `onChange` handler function.

   ```
   handleChange = (selectedList) => (e) => {
     const { lists } = this.state;
     let obj = lists?.find((filt) => filt.id === selectedList.id);
     obj.innerList.forEach((fruite) => {
       if (fruite.title === e.target.name) fruite.completed = e.target.checked;
     });
     let toggledBoxes = lists.map((list) =>
       list.id === obj.id ? { ...obj } : list
     );
     this.setState({ lists: toggledBoxes });
   };
   ```
4. Pass the currently iterated list item to `handleChange` in the JSX

   ```
   {ar.innerList.map((inner) => (
     <div key={inner.id}>
       <label>
         <input
           type="checkbox"
           onChange={this.handleChange(ar)} // <-- pass current list item
           checked={inner.completed}
           name={inner.title}
           id={inner.title}
         />
         {inner.title}
       </label>
     </div>
   ))}
   ```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-select-multiple-checkbox-in-accordion-using-react]

FYI, I also updated the `handleChange` callback to use a functional state update to avoid the unnecessary pre-search for the `obj` being updated and the `completed` property mutation. You will want to do something similar to `removeChips` when you get around to using it.

```
handleChange = (selectedList) => (e) => {
  const { checked, name } = e.target;

  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    lists: prevState.lists.map((list) =>
      list.id === selectedList.id
        ? {
            ...list,
            innerList: list.innerList.map((fruite) =>
              fruite.title === name
                ? {
                    ...fruite,
                    completed: checked
                  }
                : fruite
            )
          }
        : list
    )
  }));
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for solution and explanation... Really appriciated!